# Let's talk about the reputation limit

Tags: support, reputation

"[You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day.](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation)"
Wait, *what*?

---

On several days I've found myself surpassing 200 rep - I get more upvotes than that. Which brings me to these questions:

***Why is there a limit?***
I couldn't find a page explaining why we cap it off. If you continue to make progress, why does the system decide that you've done enough? Why, when the community continues to vote, saying "you deserve more today", does the site say "actually, the community is wrong"?

***What happens to reputation you earn after the daily limit?***
Does it simply vanish? Do you get it the next day? Let me know if another page explains this, I couldn't find this information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Why* there's a limit has been answered on [What is the reasoning behind the reputation cap?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22447/274942), [Revisiting the rep cap (yes, again)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136059/274942) and the questions linked therein. There are a number of reasons:

- It ensures that you can't game the system by having one post that hits the Hot Network Questions list in a day and piles up obscene amounts of reputation, or by posting loads of posts one after another and getting reputation simply through probability.
- It keeps people coming back to the site.
- It forces people to do other things around the site - edit, review, etc. - when they can't gain rep, or go outside, spend time with actual people, or do other normal stuff.
- It means that you need long-term dedication to build up reputation, rather than getting 1,000 points in one UTC day and suddenly having a lot of privileges you don't know how to use. This is [Jeff's logic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/136060/274942).
- You get addicted through the gamification of wanting to go back the next day. It also combats the addiction by limiting it.

Yes, the reputation vanishes into thin air, never to return. You do, however, gain reputation points from bounties you earn (25-500 apiece), answers of yours which are accepted (15), and answers you accept (2).

Lest you think that I'm biased in favor of the cap, I've missed out on a solid 330 reputation points so far today, by my math, because of it.

Comment: This answer is more thorough than mine.  Use it.  Though you should add that bounty and acceptance rep does not vanish.

Comment: @James Thanks. Done.

Comment: Now that I know you are at max for the day I am going to go upvote a bunch of your stuff. :D